# looping through json to check if somedata exists if not show does not using ngFor and ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, loops

I'm looping through a json api with *ngFor while looping through the data, I want to check for every person, if it has no Family
So using Angular ngIf I want to check if that exists and display the data and if not show No family of this person.

JSON

```
{
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "Childrens": [
        {
          "name": "maria k",
          "age": "4 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "mary k",
          "age": "2 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "jon k",
          "age": "7 year"
        },
         ],
      "steps": [
        "1. abcdef",
        "2. 123456789",
        "3. mnbvcxz."
      ],
      "Family": [
        "Somedata",
        "Somedata",
        "Somedata"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "Childrens": [
        {
          "name": "Some name",
          "age": "4 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "Some name",
          "age": "2 year"
        }   
      ],
      "steps": [
        "1. abcdef",
        "2. 123456789",
        "3. mnbvcxz."
      ],
      // No Family Data here 
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do it like this but does not work

HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let onePerson of person.Family">
          <div *ngIf="!onePerson.Family?.length">
              <p class="text-center"> Family does not Exists</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Ok, I want to show if that family object array exists or not I was able use the correct ngFor to show all however I have empty where family does not exists. So I want to show messsage

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<div *ngFor="let person of person.Family">
  <div *ngIf="person?.Family">
          <p class="text-center"> {{person}} </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT

Your ngFor should be as,

```
<div *ngFor="let personObj of person.persons">
          <div *ngIf="personObj?.Family">
              <p class="text-center"> {{personObj | json}} </p>
          </div>
         <div *ngIf="!personObj?.Family">
              <p class="text-center"> Family does not Exists</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

**[`STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgkx35?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: @codesmooth7 There is an issue with the ngFor, check the demo

Comment: edited again friend the main part if family object array exists show the family if not display message.

Comment: it is simple as this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgkx35?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: the json is not same you edited { "person": [ this part. That's important to me can please show how to do using same exact my posted RAW JSON data?

Comment: you just have to use then person.persons in the ngFor

Comment: It doesn't work friend can you tutorial it on stackblitz please?

Comment: export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMessage: string;
  public person = [];

  constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.personService.getRecipes()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.person = data;
      },
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );

}

Comment: dude check properly

Comment: Dude I just did! the JSON data in the ts is not same

Comment: i have not updated in the stackblitz since its just a sample, check the edited part

Comment: I can see that data with using your edited version. However, I cannot see it with my files like the original data I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

THE HTML PART STARTS

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons.person">
       <div *ngIf="!person.Family; else haveFamily">
          <p class="text-center">Family does not Exists</p> 
       </div>
       <ng-template #haveFamily>
          <div>
             <p class="text-center"> {{person | json}} </p>
          </div>
       </ng-template>
 </div>
```

And also a small suggestion you JSON has comma missing issues. I cleaned it made it perfect Please find the JSON Below

```
persons =  {
  "person": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "Childrens": [
        {
          "name": "maria k",
          "age": "4 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "mary k",
          "age": "2 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "jon k",
          "age": "7 year"
        }
      ],
      "steps": [
        "1. abcdef",
        "2. 123456789",
        "3. mnbvcxz."
      ],
      "Family": [
        "Somedata",
        "Somedata",
        "Somedata"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "Childrens": [
        {
          "name": "Some name",
          "age": "4 year"
        },
        {
          "name": "Some name",
          "age": "2 year"
        }
      ],
      "steps": [
        "1. abcdef",
        "2. 123456789",
        "3. mnbvcxz."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```